# Помогите сделать так массив упорядочи каждую строку по убыванию элементов

Tags: c++

Вот мой код в С++. Подскажите что можно вписать чтобы массив упорядочил элементы по убыванию

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "iostream"
#include"stdafx.h"
#include "ctime"
#include"stdlib.h"

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    const int ROWS = 50;
    const int COLS = 100;

    int arr[ROWS][COLS];

    for (int m = 0; m < ROWS; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < COLS; n++)
        {
            arr[m][n] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < ROWS; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < COLS; n++)
        {
            cout << arr[m][n] << "\t";
        }

        cout << end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если программа учебная, то может подойти хотя бы [метод пузырька](https://code-live.ru/solutions/cpp/3/) или любой другой метод сортировки -- с учётом убывания, разумеется :)